# Data binding an ItemsControl

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

I am trying to write a card game using UWP and have come up with yet another stumbling block.
In my ViewModel I have a property called PlayersList.  PlayersList contains  XPosition and YPosition properties which are intended to be absolute positions on a Canvas of each player object.  I have the following code in my UI:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayerList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Canvas.Top="{Binding YPosition}" 
                        Canvas.Left="{Binding XPosition}">
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Problem is that the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate is not being applied.  It seems that all of the items  in PlayerList is being rendered at Canvas positions 0,0 one on top of the other.  If I comment out the ItemsControl.ItemsPanel block of code, all the items in the list get rendered as if in a vertical StackPanel.
I have tried changing the list to an Observable Collection and even just a single object with the same results.  I have even gone so far as to add a test TextBlock to the ItemTemplate which does not get rendered which proves to me that the template is not being applied.
Shouldn't this work as written?  What am I missing here?

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Inside your `DataTemplate`, shouldn't there be a `x:DataType`? For more clear view, post the code of your viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for the response @Muzib Even with `x:DataType` set to the control containing the properties, I get the same results.

Comment: Your xaml basically says that your ItemsControl has a `Canvas` in it as ItemsPanel, and inside this Canvas, you want more other Canvases.. is that what you actually want?

Comment: No.  My intent is a single `Canvas` and on that canvas `PlayerControls` are placed at specific `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`  locations which are defined as properties in the `PlayerControl`.  I thought that the block of code in the    `ItemTemplate` was my means of setting the position of the `PlayerControl` on the `Canvas  not to create more canvases.

Comment: What does `PlayerControl` derive from? Is it a user control, or a ViewModel ?

Comment: `PlayerControl` is a user control.  'PlayerControls`  is a property defined in a ViewModel and contains a  `List` of `PlayerControl`.

Comment: then `ItemsControl` isn't for you I think. I wonder why don't you just use a simple Grid? Then you can set the top and left Margin of those `PlayerControl` to position them wherever you want. May be I am not understanding your special case.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. UWP is new to me and I clearly don't understand how to translate what's in my head to working code.  The reason I chose a canvas is because of its absolute positioning capabilities where as a grid is confined to defined rows and columns.   Basically what I am trying to do is place a (variable) list of poker players around a semi-circle playing table. The players positions and angle  will vary depending on the number of players. It is not clear to me why you say  `ItemsControl`  is not for me but I will look into it, Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Muzib After playing around with `ItemsControl` I now see what you are saying.  I am not using the control as it is intended to be used -- I am cleary misunderstanding it's functionality.  Looks like I am going to have to come up with a different strategy.  Thanks for guiding me away from a direction of no results.

Comment: I found the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3e05a646-1d92-4cec-8999-38eda69d4b42/uwpxaml-data-binding-an-itemscontrol?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn, and it has answer, FEC-4RP answered this question accurately, please check.

Comment: @Muzib Could you please elaborate as to why `ItemsControl` is not appropriate?

Comment: Did you read the official document of `ItemsControl`? It says there that this control is usually used to show list of data. I don't think you are trying to show a list of data. But yes, a lot of things is also possible in unusual way. Good luck.